# How to set width of the dashboard to be 100% in Dynamics CRM 2015 Update 1 online

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2015

I'm trying to make the width of the dashboard to be 100%

While inspecting the html there is a div element with `class=".ms-crm-Dashboard-Area"` which has `max-width:1920px; min-width:400px`

I tried adding JavaScript web resource, added the file but when I add it to the section I get "Invalid web resource type for form..."

```
$("ms-crm-Dashboard-Area").css("max-width","2500px");
```

So could someone please tell me how to get rid of the max-width and set it to 100% or to change the max-width via JavaScript?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that isn't a supported change - so there will be no easy way to do it and you shouldn't try.

If an upgrade changes the DOM layout your script will break. The dashboard CSS is pretty much fixed as Microsoft have provided it. All we can do is move the elements around inside using the out of the box layout controls.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I concur with you on this as well, it's weird why Microsoft would restrict form dimensions on this.

Comment: @Imran is it really so weird? You have a product to customise and extended. Each customisation or extensible point requires Microsoft to build something. So I can see why in this case that something doesn't exist. Its less of a restriction, and more that something isn't available.